# Efficient way to remove Sparse matrix row having large data in R

Tags: r

I have a large sparse Matrix. Based on the number of elements in a row, I want to remove the row of the sparse Matrix. The first step is to obtain the indexes of the row that has less that 5 elements.

number of rows = 4,000,000
number of columns = 250,000

The sparse matrix looks somewhat like this...

| A header | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | ... | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | . | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | . | . |
| Second | . | . | 1 | 1 | . | . | . |
| Third | 1 | . | . | . | . | . | . |
| Fourth | 1 | . | . | . | 1 | . | . |
| nth | 1 | . | . | . | . | . | . |

I could use rowSums, and remove the row based on the output.

```
items <- c()
for(i in 1: nrow(sparse_matrix){
  if(rowSums(sparse_matrix)[i] < 3){
    items <- append(items, i)
  }
}
```

However, this takes 1hr 30mins to go through around 10,000 rows which is really slow.

What would be an efficient solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you calculate `rowSums(sparse_matrix)` at every iteration of the loop, which is inefficient. Second, doing `append(items, i)` in a loop is also inefficient.

My solution without a loop at all:

```
items = which(rowSums(sparse_matrix) < 3)
```

Comment: Thank you. Here's what I want to do next...I want to be able to remove the rows of the Sparse Matrix which are less than 3. 

I used ...
```
reversed_items <- rev(items)

for(i in 1:length(reversed_items){
  sparse_matrix <- sparse_matrix[-reversed_items[[i]], , drop=FALSE]
}
```

This works, but is extremely inefficient. How can I do it in a better way?

Comment: Oh, once again you are using a loop where none needed. First, get a list of rows which you want to keep, like `items = which(rowSums(sparse_matrix) >= 3)`, then extract them `sparse_matrix  = sparse_matrix [items,]`. That's it. Feel free to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following up @AndreyShabalin's answer with an example:

### example

Set up a matrix with the specified dimensions and 1 million non-zero elements:

```r
nr <- 4e6; nc <- 2.5e4; ns <- 1e6
m <- Matrix(0, nrow = nr, ncol = nc)
set.seed(101)
i <- sample(nr, size = ns, replace = TRUE)
j <- sample(nc, size = ns, replace = TRUE)
m[cbind(i,j)] <- 1
```

### subset

```r
system.time(m2 <- m[rowSums(m) > 3, ]) ## 0.03 seconds
nrow(m2)  ## 543
```

By avoiding (1) recomputing `rowSums()` and (2) not growing a vector, we make this very fast.

```r
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  logical = m[rowSums(m) > 3, ],
  which = m[which(rowSums(m) > 3), ]
)
```

For reasons I don't understand, the solution with `which` is actually slightly **faster** than the logical-indexing solution (median of 30 vs 35 milliseconds ...)

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 logical 33.13682 35.07974 45.65183 35.61339 37.09483 160.3382   100   b
   which 27.90955 29.90988 37.06513 30.38864 31.76437 153.8702   100  a
```